How to make D&D easier for kids?
I have a 12-year-old brother who I noticed wanting to play RPG with his friends. I told him I would be okay to be the master and help them create the characters. I asked them for the weapon they wanted and the race and the class they would like to play as. With that, I would be able to create the rest of the sheet focusing on what would be the best for each class. I already had a beginner level campaign I made myself that worked fine when I played with some friends, so I was going to try it again with them.
The thing is, none of them seemed to be interested in doing the research for the races and characters by the book, because they felt a bit overwhelmed by all the information. How can I make the extensive list of choices and options at character creation more accessible and engaging for younger players?

Are you asking how to make D&D (and if so - any version or in particular, 5e) easier for kids, or are you asking what other RPG systems exist for kids that have less of a learning curve? Your title and body ask two different things. Also note the second one would likely run afoul of our "no shopping questions" policy.

Your second paragraph asking for recommendations has some answers here: Are there any good tabletop RPGs for young beginning players?

You may find more helpful Q&As looking through [tag:kids] tag.

@TreeSpawned Think about it like this: the tags [dnd-5e] and [adnd-1e] are used to indicate an actual game, whereas the generic [dungeons-and-dragons] tag is about the idea of D&D, not the actual game. This question is asking about playing an actual game, we just don’t know which one.

The old D&D Basic Set back in the goold old days solved that problem (I cherish mine, which is now a true antique). I haven't played in decades. Is there really no such basic set in the day of 5e?

Hmm question details are a bit with conflict with the title. The average 12 year old, given normal education, should be at a reading level and have an attention span that doesn't require any special treatment. Everyone is a bit different of course, but I'm not sure the answers here can be meaningfully compared to getting adults with no significant prior board or role playing game experience into the games.

@NobodytheHobgoblin Yeah, english is not my first language, so i got a bit confused while writing. I actually meant either, so if I could make DnD easier for them would be nice, but I would be okay with using a different system.

@Cubic considering that all of them either spend a bunch of time on tik tok, or do the same with youtube shorts, so their attention span is already a bit affected.


none of them seemed to be interested in doing the research

Yeah. They are 12 year olds. They don't want to research, they want to play. If you had introduced them to soccer, you would have started by kicking a ball around, not explaining team composition and the differences in 4-5-1 to 4-3-3 tactics. They would fall asleep before ever tying their laces and kicking a ball. So start with the action, start by playing, not by teaching theory (or having them look up theory).
So first, prepare characters. Some stereotypical ones. Elf Ranger. Human Knight. Dwarf Warrior. Priest. Mage. Simple, stereotypical. Make sure there is enough that everyone can pick one and nobody has to "take what is left". It doesn't matter whether the group would "work". This isn't optimized D&D, this is just having fun getting into the action. The same way that 5 boys with 3 wanting to be goalie will never make a working soccer team, but you have to start somewhere. And trying to get them to understand why the theory says you cannot do it that way is a sure way to lose them.
They still don't know what those characters I just described mean. Without meaning decision making is hard and fruitless. So prepare either miniatures that represent them, or if you don't have minis, print pictures. Pick 3-5 attributes or short descriptions for each.
Like:


Elf Ranger: Good Archer. Likes animals. Can sneak.
Human Knight: Good with a Sword. Has a horse. Likes helping others.
Dwarven Warrior: Good with an Axe. Has a heavy armor. Very tough.


That's just examples, obviously it depends on how you build the characters. But make it easy to pick something. Very much like board games, where your character sheet is actually just a card with a picture, a few words and 3-5 numbers.
Then play. Do not explain things too much. Getting stuff explained is literally their day job, they do it 6+ hours every weekday. Booooring. Just imagine the first person that taught you D&D to go "well, before you can be an Elf, you have to understand how double-entry accounting works, let me tell you real quick, here on page 24..." and that would have been it. No D&D for you, you would have run screaming. So do not imitate their day job, action first, explanation only when necessary.
So take those characters they picked and put them in some situations. Not a full adventure, they may have picked a choice not suited for the adventure or not enough players or too many, or all wizards. But it doesn't matter. Make up an adventure on the fly. Fudge all details. It is your job to make sure they succeed as a team on their adventure. Even if that means their big success is clubbing a single goblin to death in their all wizard party.
Make sure they do something. And if they ask, only then explain what you do and why.
I would also recommend as many props as possible. Not goofy ones, just things that help all at the table imagine the same scene. Miniatures are great, printouts can do the same thing. Draw maps. Make sure everyone is on the same page when it comes to "who is where" in the fictional room or castle. If some of them run out to get a refill for their drink or need to use the restroom or their mom comes in to ask something, when they can focus back on the game, it should be instantly visible what is going on. Kids have enough imagination, the challenge is to have all kids have the same picture in their mind. Give them something to engage with. Something practical, that is, not rules.

Introduce the system with pre-built characters, then let them create new characters when they're more familiar with the system.
In my experience, the primary challenge of character creation as a new-to-the-system player is that you need to be familiar with the system to really make sense of the choices presented at character creation. If I only had a dollar for every time I heard a new player say:

That sounds cool, but what does it mean?

You really do need to have some familiarity with the mechanics of the system before you can get the most out of character creation.
To get around this, what I do now when introducing players to a game is to get a general idea of the character theme they want to play, then build a character for them. I will run a few sessions with the pre-built characters to let the players get a better grasp of all the details of gameplay, and once they're more comfortable with the rules, I'll help them create a new character, if they want to do that.

+1 for this, and not just for kids. I find this is the best way to introduce inexperienced new players to their first system. (Folks who’ve played a lot of videogames or RPG-like board games might be fine with making characters from scratch.)

Use a starter set, and ready-to-go characters
Use a simple game system. I recommend to use a simpler system than full-on 5th edition. Core 5th Edition caters to all kinds of players, and has a huge wealth of options to choose from, with so many different races, classes, backgrounds, and with rules for 20 levels of play. You do not need that at first.  Wizards of the Coast instead provides starter sets, that are specifically designed for beginning players, and come with a simplified rule book for level 1-3 play, and ready-to-play characters, that shield the players from the extra effort to have to design their own characters. The original Basic D&D game is another option, for example the famous Red Box (available as a free PDF on the Internet Archive).
Provide fully developed characters to pick. Even if you do not want to use the starter set, pre-generate a few characters, describe them, and let them pick one of those. You can even have back stories that relate the characters to each other. I've used this successfully. At the beginning, everything is so new that the players have their hands full imagining themselves as this other character, and have no is no need to realize an own character concept. And you do not need to explain 12 different classes to them, and 17 different races and subraces, and 13 different backgrounds. These players want to play a fantasy game, more than wanting to play a specific character concept to explore new nuances of the fantasy game. Just give them a few characters to pick from, which is way faster and more fun.
Build it for them, based on narrative. If you really want them to make up their own character, just ask them what kind of character they want to play, without basing it on the detailed mechanical benefits. Just ask them if they want to build a human, elf, or dwarf, independent of the mechanics, for example. If they want to play a fighter, or a magic-user, and maybe, a wild barbarian if a fighter, or knight with armor. Then develop the character for them. In this, I would not use optional features like feats, at least at first.

This depends a lot on how fluent you are with the system.  Since I spend (too much) time memorizing RPG rules, I'll give my two cents from the perspective of someone with a lot of system knowledge.
Also, your question seems mainly concerned with character creation, so that is what I will be primarily addressing.
Take their ideas and translate them into options.
Once you've hooked the player on what the fantasy world is like, just have a conversation about character creation.  Specifically, try to get "soft" answers from them that you can convert into "hard" answers for a character sheet.
For instance, ask them what they see their character being like.  Guide the first question along the lines of "What kind of land are you from?  Do you hail from the Dwarven Kingdoms, the Elven Woodlands, or perhaps a human port city?"  Or perhaps the more point-blank questions of "What kind of person do you want to be in this world" or "How do you like to solve problems?  Stealth, smooth talking, clever fighting, blasting stuff with fire?"
As soon as your player starts thinking on that, they'll have some kind of picture.  Maybe they won't give you much, maybe they give you too much - just try to pare it down to what you need.  They might say "Yeah, I want to live in the woods."  From there, prompt if that means an elf with a connection to nature, or maybe a rugged human survivalist.  If you get an answer like "I want to be a middle aged pirate with a cutlas who abandoned his crew for-" then you cut them off for a second to focus on the part you need.  In this case, if the character is a human.
Then, ask what the player wants the character to be able to do.  You should be able to get a gist of this from the previous question, but this is where you present options.  For the woodsy elf, perhaps you could say "How deep is your elf's connection to nature?  Are you religiously devoted to nature?  Or do you see nature as a source of power and friends? Or maybe it's just something you have to survive in?"  This question would whittle down class options to Druid, Ranger, or a martial class respectively.
From there, just give the player flavorful lists of options that you can translate into classes, feats, and paths.  Each time, let the player know what you're doing so they don't feel too separated from the game - something like "Okay, since you want your pirate captain to be a sneaky, smooth-talking guy who fights dirty, go ahead and write Rogue up on that top line.  That'll let you take the sneaky abilities you want, like a Sneak Attack ability that's going to help you do a bunch of extra damage if you can surprise or outflank your enemy."
Remember that not knowing where to start may not mean a lack of enthusiasm.
For me, personally, I find it very easy to assume my players are a lot less excited about my campaign than they actually are.  When there's confusion about the system mixed with some aprehension about the unknown, this effect is magnified.
So whatever happens, just stay cool and stay the course.  Let them mess up, let them learn, and let your players' ideas be suboptimal or rough around the edges.  As long as your players feel like they have some kind of agency in the whole process, you're golden.  Making a second character is leagues easier than the first.

+1 I love your answer as it gets them to use their imagination going and potentially have some excitement, affinity with and investment in their characters. However, I wonder what you'd do when you have 5 or 6 of them as they may get bored waiting to have their turn. I don't know if you could cover what you have done or do in this case.

@Senmurv Running a game with 5 or more players is difficult enough when they do read the books and understand the system.  If someone approached me for advice on running such a game with 5 or more new, unconfident kids, I'd flatly tell them to cut down on the number of players.  It's not that it can't be done, of course, but it would require a lot of experience with both running games and how the kids themselves behave.

In addition to all the great advice provided, I wanted to make a plug for D&D's officially published books targeted for children: A Young Adventurer's Guide.
https://www.penguinrandomhouse.com/series/EJB/dungeons-and-dragons-young-adventurers-guides/
They have tons of books, but the first few books are basically children-oriented rewrites of the core rule books: Warriors & Weapons + Wizards & Spells = PHB, Monsters & Creatures = MM, and Dungeons & Tombs = DMG.  You don't need to buy all of them, just start with one (I'd recommend Warriors & Weapons).
These books have absolutely no rules or numbers, it's entirely fluff text.  They're very light reads, about 100 8"x6" pages each with lots of pictures, that simply describe the world of D&D (2-3 paragraph descriptions of races, classes, armor and weapons, etc.)

Good shout! I made my own version of this for adult players too, as we wanted to get the characters done in an hour or so for 6 people and get started.

Are they really interested if they won't even do that much?
If they are not even willing to read enough to figure out what races and classes they want, are you sure they are interested? Are they doing this only because they think you want to? Or perhaps just as a way to spend time with you?
I started playing when I was around 11. My cousin introduced me. He helped me make my first character (almost made it for me), but I skimmed the character creation section before and chose the important parts with a bit of guidance from him. I read the Player's Handbook thoroughly not long after and the Dungeon Master's book not long after that.
If your brother isn't willing to at least skim the PHB to pick the big stuff, he may not be that interested in the first place.
Consider offering them premade characters.
The other thing to do is to make or acquire a small selection of characters for the party and just let them skim the sheets and pick one. You only need to get enough sheets for your players, randomly decide who gets to pick first, and then go around until everyone has picked a character.
There's a very good chance they will end up not liking the character. But its a low effort way for them to try their first session. They can then ask to swap characters or build new ones when they have seen a bit more about how the game works.
Its not so low effort for you of course, but if you were planning to mostly make their characters anyway, it probably isn't much more effort than you would be doing anyway.

I'd say start with a simpler system that doesn't require a whole lot of reading to start the game. At the end of the day all the fancy rules can enhance the experience but the main fun (at least in my opinion) is coming up with clever solutions to problems and telling stories with friends.
I personally lean more into narrative based games like Heart, but I think if the end goal is to get into DND 5e it might make more sense to start with an osr style game like Knave, Mausritter or Index Card RPG. They are all really simple and rules lite so you can just jump straight into the action.
I've found it far easier to ease people in with a simpler game than to try to make a game like DND 5e simplified enough to get someones foot in the door.
